# Node serve command returns empty response

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I'm building and hosting a react app and the script to run it is as follows:

```
npm run build;
npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

But when I run, it says it's running on `localhost:5000`, but when I go to it it returns an empty response.

I'm running this from inside a docker container that inherits from `node` image.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    frontend:
        build: ./frontend
        command: ["./docker_up.sh"]
        restart: always
        volumes:
           - ./frontend:/app/frontend
           - node-modules:/app/frontend/node_modules
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
          - "5000:5000"
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
        environment:
          - MODE=PROD
volumes:
  node-modules:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app/frontend
COPY package.json /app/frontend
COPY build/* /usr/share/nginx/html/

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["docker_up.sh"]
```

docker_up.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $MODE == "PROD" ]; then
    echo "Using production settings.";
    apt-get update;
    apt-get install xsel;
    npm run build;

    npm install -g serve
    serve -s build
else
    echo "Using development settings."
    npm start;
fi;
```

Comment: What is in your Dockerfile?

Comment: @Yuankun Added to the post.